# Debugging a CUDA code generating stock paths with geometric Brownian motion method

Tags: cuda

This code is supposed to generating stock paths with geometric Brownian motion method. For each path, I have `10` steps, but, as you can see below, from the third path, everything there is `0`, which is not what I want. Where is the error?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <device_launch_parameters.h>
#include <curand_kernel.h>

const int numSims(10);
const int threadBlockSize(4);

__global__ void generatePaths(float* path)
{
    float r=0.1;
    float sigma=0.3;
    float S0=100;
    float K=100;
    float t=1;

    int steps=10;
    float dt=t/float(steps);

    curandState s;
    int tid=blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
    curand_init(tid, 0, 0, &s);

    float *value=path+tid;
    float S=S0;
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<steps; ++i)
    {
        S=S*expf((r-0.5*sigma*sigma)*dt+sigma*sqrt(dt)*curand_normal(&s));
        *(path+tid+i)=S;
    }
}

int main()
{
    dim3 grid;
    dim3 block;
    block.x=threadBlockSize;
    grid.x=(numSims+threadBlockSize-1)/threadBlockSize;

    int steps=10;
    float *da;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&da, numSims*steps*sizeof(float));
    generatePaths<<<grid, block>>>(da);

    float *values;
    values=(float*)malloc(numSims*steps*sizeof(float));
    cudaMemcpy(values, da, numSims*steps*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    for(int i=0; i<numSims; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<steps; j++)
        {
            std::cout<<values[i*steps+j]<<" ";
        }
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The result is

103.381 97.1031 106.928 114.18 120.802 98.2669 114.038 106.057 126.741 136.836

125.589 124.903 123.564 102.781 125.09 71.5134 89.9109 92.4751 184.371 101.023

162.256 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: What this code is expected to do?

Comment: You didnt ask a question. What is your question.

Comment: Please edit your question's title into something meaningful.

Comment: You need to provide some background and context if you want an answer. Not everyone can, or has the time to, look at your code and infer what you want it to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

should't it be

```
    *(path + tid * steps + i) = S;
```

instead of

```
    *(path+tid+i)=S;
```

?

your version has race condition - different threads are writing to the same memory element

upd:
right, @talonmies point about bad memory access is valid - your grid has 3 blocks and 4 threads per block, processing `steps` elements each, but allocated memory has a lesser size. You could pass the size to the kernel and add a check `if(tid > size) return;`, or change your grid to fit the task better.

Comment: Yes, that is the problem. But the code will fail with an out of bounds memory access if that is fixed without adding range checking to the kernel.